# Moment of Inertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

The Question is

> A thin uniform rod of mass  and length  is bent at its center so that the two segments are now
>   perpendicular to each other. Find its moment of inertia about an axis perpendicular to its plane and
>   passing through
>   (a) the point where the two segments meet, and
>   (b) the midpoint of the line connecting its two ends.

[image]

Here is my question, where does the one over twelve come from in the third sentence of the solution?

Comment: As a community, we should either vote to close or answer. It's silly to just leave this question here. I am voting to close.

Comment: Why do you want to close this question?  It seemed well laid out to me.

Comment: ...from $2\left(\frac{1}{96}+\frac{1}{32}\right)=2\left(\frac{1}{96}+\frac{3}{96}\right)=2\frac{4}{96}=\frac{1}{12}$

Comment: @InertialIgnorance It's not really a question on a physics concept.  It's a question on why a specific integer constant shows up when deriving an equation.  It's less of a conceptual answer and more of a mathematical one.  Also showing an image of text instead of writing your own is generally not good formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is the question good, nor is my answer.

But this may help you:

[image]

I cannot help better than this.